# Google Custom Search Engine - backendError

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-custom-search

Can any one tell why this issue raises. But no info how to resolve this issue as there is no enough description.

```
{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"backendError", "message"=>"Backend Error"}], "code"=>500, "message"=>"Backend Error"}
```

I am seeing this issue, only in  production environment.  Please suggest some fix.

Comment: can you put exact error log (full terminal trace?)

Comment: @RonakBhatt {"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"backendError", "message"=>"Backend Error"}], "code"=>500, "message"=>"Backend Error"} is the exact error message from google custom search client.

Comment: hey I think you have the internal error (The request failed due to an internal error.) so u can post code so we can find out

Comment: @ronakBhatt this is not issue with my code.. this is error given by google custom search engine. You can create custom search engine here and try an api request. https://cse.google.com/cse/all

Comment: Did you find any information on this error?

Answer (score 2):

> For Google Custom Search Engine, I am sending first_name, last_name,
>   company_name as parameters.
>
> The first_name or last_name is having length of more than 255
>   characters. So, Google CSE throws backenderror for large inputs in
>   terms of length.
>
> We have to send first_name and last_name and company name within the
>   length of 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

> If Search query length is more than 1828 characters google cse is
>   throwing internal server error. So make sure query length is <= 1828
>   characters.